# Глобальные контроллеры(модули) laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день!
Подскажите как реализовать сайдбары? То есть хочу сделать контроллеры которые бы отрабатывали и выводили контент на каждой странице, независимо от основного контента и не были привязаны к роутам или были бы привязаны сразу ко всем.

Использую laravel 5.4, перерыл уже всю документацию, ничего похожего не нашел :(

Comment: можно на статических методах реализовать, а можно как советуют взять пакет для виджетов

Comment: Если нужно выводить повторяющиеся данные для всех представлений. Можно воспользоваться View Composer из коробки. Про это написано в   документации. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужны виджеты https://github.com/arrilot/laravel-widgets
Вставляете их в нужном месте шаблона

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!